# Get route to controller symfony2

Tags: symfony, url-routing

I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible to get the route (as defined in the routes.yml file) to a specific controller?

An example may be helpful.

```
class SomeRandomController extends Controller {
    public function showAction($id) {
        //Get the entity and return with a Response object
    }
}
```

in routes.yml...

```
some_random_show:
    pattern: /some/random/thing/{id}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "MyBundle:SomeRandom:show", id: 0 }
```

So what I would like is get the route name (as in `some_random_show`) if I have the class name and its namespace (as in `MyBundle\Controller\SomeRandomController`). Any ideas?

**EDIT** Let's say I know the action, as I specifically want the show action for a controller.

The rationale behind this is a bit of a hack, but it comes down to me saving the class name and the id for a specific entity to the DB, and then I need to generate the show URL based on what entity class I persisted. If that makes any sense.

Comment: You also need a action name? Because route looks like defaults: { _controller: "Controller:action", id: 0 }

Comment: I do not see why would you want that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will work, mainly because Actions can have multiple routes.

But if all you want to do is mapping a specific entity class to a specific route name, you should consider writing a service for it that returns a route name based on the entity name.

The route name could be generic (e.g. convert your entity name to lowercase and replace \ with _) or you could define which entity maps to which route by hand in your config.yml.